# How to merge many(and different) cells from one row to many rows with fewer cells?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting lost at how accomplish such transformation, from(1 row with couples of the same type columns repeated 3 times):

```
NormalCol1 | NormalCol2 | col1_0 | col2_0 | col1_1 | col2_2 | col1_2 | col2_2
"AD"       | 2018-03-02 | "error"| "mess" | "warn" | "mess" | "info" | "mess"
```

to(3 rows with those 6 columns put together in 2):

```
NormalCol1 | NormalCol2 | col1   | col2 
"AD"       | 2018-03-02 | "error"| "mess"
"AD"       | 2018-03-02 | "warn" | "mess"
"AD"       | 2018-03-02 | "info" | "mess"
```

Have you ever stumbled upon such transformation? 
If yes, how did you accomplish the transformation?

Ps: the columns are fixed.

Comment: Can you please explain with better example as it is not quite clear

Comment: it could be PIVOT but this is just a guess, you need to provide an actual sample data with more explanation, as well as what you've tried so far

Comment: sounds like you need a union operation

Comment: number of columns are fixed as per mentioned?

Comment: @maulikkansara yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a `UNION ALL` query or `CROSS APPLY` (with `union all` also) or `TABLE VALUE CONSTRUCTOR`

```
SELECT NormalCol1, NormalCol2, col1 = col1_0, col2 = col2_0 FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT NormalCol1, NormalCol2, col1 = col1_1, col2 = col2_1 FROM YourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT NormalCol1, NormalCol2, col1 = col1_2, col2 = col2_2 FROM YourTable


SELECT NormalCol1, NormalCol2, col1, col2
FROM   YourTable
       CROSS APPLY
       (
           SELECT col1 = col1_0, col2 = col2_0
           UNION ALL
           SELECT col1 = col1_1, col2 = col2_1
           UNION ALL
           SELECT col1 = col1_2, col2 = col2_2
       ) a

SELECT NormalCol1, NormalCol2, col1, col2
FROM   YourTable
       CROSS APPLY
       (
           VALUES (col1_0, col2_0), 
                  (col1_1, col2_1),
                  (col1_2, col2_2)
       ) c (col1, col2)
```

Comment: Thanks you, your methods are all valid, except now I'm dealing with a join after this select, and from that join(inner to get some IDs) comes out copies of the records, do you know why?

Comment: or better, start a new question

Comment: @Eugene . . . This answers the question you asked (and is the best answer in my opinion, particularly using `values()`).  If you have another question, ask it as *another* question . . . and remember to accept whichever answer you think is best.

Answer (score 1):

You should go with `UnPivot` operation.
Please take a note that here `Where` clause  added in the end of query is most important.
Without it, we haven't told SQL Server how the second set of unpivoted data matches the first.  Without the WHERE , it will do a cross join, resulting in repetitive data for col1 for each unique data for col2.

```
  declare @tbl as table
(
NormalCol1 varchar(50),
NormalCol2 varchar(50),
col1_0 varchar(50),
col2_0 varchar(50),
col1_1 varchar(50),
col2_1 varchar(50),
col1_2 varchar(50),
col2_2 varchar(50)
)

insert into @tbl
select 'AD','2018-03-02','error','mess','warn','mess','info','mess'



select NormalCol1,NormalCol2,col1,col2 from @tbl
unpivot
(
col1 for details in (col1_0,col1_1,col1_2)
)unp
unpivot
(
col2 for data in (col2_0,col2_1,col2_2)
)unp
WHERE RIGHT(details,1) = RIGHT(data,1)
```

Comment: Doesn't produce anything this approach ._.

Comment: Still doesn't produce anything

Comment: I have prepared temp table as added in answer with your sample data and it is generating output.

Comment: It does work in your example, still I have trouble to see it working on my data, the structure is the same, damn me.