# How to merge the columns with a following join based on the merged columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[How to merge many(and different) cells from one row to many rows with fewer cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51979224/how-to-merge-manyand-different-cells-from-one-row-to-many-rows-with-fewer-cell/51979518?noredirect=1#comment90918779_51979518)

There I got half of the answer because after that step there's a table to join on top of the merged data that's about that data.
So now, for example, there're 2 tables, `MainTable` and `Types`(from which I take the `Id`s. 

And goes from(`MainTable`):

```
Name | Date       | Type_0 | Mess_0 | Type_1 | Mess_1 | Type_2 | Mess_2 
"AD" | 2018-03-02 | "error"| "mess" | "warn" | "mess" | "info" | "mess"
```

To(`MainTable`):

```
Name | Date       | Type   | Mess   | TypeId
"AD" | 2018-03-02 | "error"| "mess" | 1
"AD" | 2018-03-02 | "warn" | "mess" | 2
"AD" | 2018-03-02 | "info" | "mess" | 3
```

With `TypeId` obtained from the table `Types`.
The name of the column Type_X has it's `Id` and `Description` in `Types`.
The final query looks like:

```
SELECT Name,Date,Type,Mess,T.Id
FROM   MainTable
   CROSS APPLY
   (
       SELECT Type = Type_0, Mess = Mess_0, ColName = 'Type_0'
       UNION ALL
       SELECT Type = Type_1, Mess = Mess_1, ColName = 'Type_1'
       UNION ALL
       SELECT Type = Type_2, Mess = Mess_2, ColName = 'Type_2'
   ) TM
INNER JOIN Types T
ON TM.ColName LIKE T.Description + '%'
```

Without the last inner join I get what I want, but after the last inner join I get triple copies of the last union:

```
SELECT Type = Type_2, Mess = Mess_2, ColName = 'Type_2'
```

Which messes up everything, like:

```
Name | Date       | Type   | Mess   | TypeId
"AD" | 2018-03-02 | "error"| "mess" | 1
"AD" | 2018-03-02 | "warn" | "mess" | 2
"AD" | 2018-03-02 | "info" | "mess" | 3
"AD" | 2018-03-02 | "info" | "mess" | 3
"AD" | 2018-03-02 | "info" | "mess" | 3
```

Anybody has a clue?

Ps: `Types` table on request:

```
Id | Description
1  | 'HVaR_3Y_6M'
2  | 'HVaR_3Y_1Y'
3  | 'HVaR_3Y'
```

Comment: Any chance at fixing the data structures? The real issue you have here is your table violates 1NF which makes querying it incredibly painful.

Comment: As much as it pains me, no. @SeanLange

Comment: Can you post your Types table? The problem is in the join there but we can't see that table.

Comment: Ummm given your sample data your query would not return anything because there is no value in ColName that is even close to the values in the Types table. This is probably a pretty easy solution but the problem is just too confusing currently.

Comment: Because the former example about is indeed an example, imagine rows being named like HVaR_3Y_6M_Type for the final Type and HVaR_3Y_6M_Mess for Mess

Comment: Instead of making us guess what the problem is on data that doesn't exist can you post data that is representative of the issue? Because with the data you posted this is not reproducible.

Comment: If you have values for ColName that match the Description column in the Types table then you should not use like and a wildcard. But without better clarification this is just me making a guess.

Comment: "Hvar_3y" is a prefix for all three descriptions. It matches three times. I also presume you've got the match condition backward.

Comment: Aren't you just wanting to join on type id?

Comment: @shawnt00 Bingo! I think this is the issue indeed :D
Now thinking how to work around it...

Comment: @shawnt00 Let me try... YES, it works, no more duplicates... Please write down an answer!
Ps: it's a pity that there's need to rely on hard-coded Ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues is apparently that `HVaR_3Y` is a prefix for all three descriptions and so it matches three times unlike the other two.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the final row has multiple matches in the Types table. If you want the result of the cross apply (main table & TM) to remain the same no matter what's in the Types table, use a Left Join:

```
SELECT Name,Date,Type,Mess,T.Id
FROM   MainTable
   CROSS APPLY
   (
       SELECT Type = Type_0, Mess = Mess_0, ColName = 'Type_0'
       UNION ALL
       SELECT Type = Type_1, Mess = Mess_1, ColName = 'Type_1'
       UNION ALL
       SELECT Type = Type_2, Mess = Mess_2, ColName = 'Type_2'
   ) TM
LEFT JOIN Types T
ON TM.ColName LIKE T.Description + '%'
```

Comment: Still produces the copies, to give you the real example of T.Description, there are only 3 descriptions in there:

    `HVaR_3Y_6M
    HVaR_3Y_1Y
    HVaR_3Y`